# Laravel5 - Changing the name of primary key column with database driver

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

**I am *not* using Eloquent**.

My user table uses `userid` as primary column name (not `id`), I have UserItem that implements the Authenticatable interface and my config/auth.php looks like this:

```
'providers' => [
         'users' => [
             'driver' => 'database',
             'table' => 'user',
         ],
    ],
```

Everything works when I rename the column to 'id', but if don't do that I get this error:

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `user` where `id` = 55 limit 1)...
```

because of this code in my view (it's default, just checks whether to display login/register or logged user menu):

```
<?php if(auth()->guard()->guest()): ?>
```

it's this directive:

```
@guest
```

Where can I change it so it doesn't look for `id` but rather `userid` instead?

Comment: Just change the column to id (which it should be anyway) :/ or reimplement [`GenericUser`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/bd352a0d2ca93775fce8ef02365b03fc4fb8cbb0/src/Illuminate/Auth/GenericUser.php#L32)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `'driver' => 'database'` you are not so flexible as with `'driver' => 'eloquent'`.
I can tell you that `id` is hard coded as part of the database driver and the GenericUser class.

If you really looking for the position where the database driver do the user authentication than you have to look at:
`/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Auth/DatabaseUserProvider.php`

```
public function retrieveById($identifier)
{
    $user = $this->conn->table($this->table)->find($identifier);

    return $this->getGenericUser($user);
}
```

Here we connecting with the database and to retrieve the user by it's identifier. So far so good but this is calling the `find` method which you will find here:
`/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.php`

```
public function find($id, $columns = ['*'])
{
    return $this->where('id', '=', $id)->first($columns);
}
```

You see `id` is a fixed string for any simple find method used by the database driver. Changing it to `userid` will cause that you have to chance all your primary keys in your database and of course in all other methods that uses `id` as well.

The `GenericUser` has also `id` as a hard coded value to identify the user, see:
`/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Auth/GenericUser.php`

```
public function getAuthIdentifierName()
{
    return 'id';
}
```

So even if you change all `id` to `userid` than you can't update, because everything will be overwritten.

My advice: use Laravel Eloquent if you can, or keep the primary identifier as`id`.

*FYI: I used the Laravel 5.5 Codebase*

Comment: I see. Thanks, I'll remember naming primary columns 'id' next time a database schema is being designed.